# sqlite reporting tool

Tags: c++, sqlite, reporting

Do you know any report generator for sqlite?

I am interested in something like crystal report.

I develop in C++ for windows, I appreciate components with fewer dependencies possible.

Even a console utility that writes a pdf file may be fine for my needs.

I prefer not to use ODBC or OLE-DB or ADO ...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try eXaro: http://exaro.sourceforge.net/
It's similar to JasperReports or Crystal Reports, but requires QT. It supports SQLite.

Comment: I'm also looking for a good report generator for C++, I found some tools but I didn't try them yet, except eXaro.
When I do it, I will give you my impressions.